# Issue loading clr assembly into sql server that uses system.text.json

Tags: c#, json, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

Have a clr assembly that references System.Text.Json (.net 4.8 with SQL Server 14), when I try to load it into SQL Server (CREATE ASSEMBLY) I get:

> Assembly 'my assembly' references assembly 'system.text.json, version=4.0.1.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

Updated the server with the latest .net, obviously loading the entire .net framework into sql server isn't a good idea :)

Comment: You need to import the system.text.json as an assembly into SQL first.  Then when you import your CLR it will be there to reference.  I had similar thing come up and I just created the assembly for the missing reference first and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to **system.text.json** not being in the list of [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries#supported-libraries).

You will have to load that DLL manually via `CREATE ASSEMBLY` (it will load dependent assemblies automatically) as `UNSAFE`. However, if that assembly is not available in .NET Framework, then I'm not sure you will be able to load it (or, even if it is available in .NET Framework but is a mixed-mode assembly -- i.e. contains unmanaged code).

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  I tried loading the assembly but it pulled me into the rabbit hole of .net's version of DLL h*ll where this was dependent on that, which was dependent on that...

One would THINK System.Text.Json is the Microsoft replacement for Newtonsoft, apparently not quite yet.

Thanks for the answers.